# Error running python 2.7.3.1 on windows 7

Tags: python-2.7, windows-7-x64

I have installed Python 2.7.3.1 on my laptop (having windows 7). However, when i try to run it, i get the following error:

'windows cannot access the specified device, path or file. You may not have the appropriate permissions to access them.'

I have changed the permissions of all the folders to full control. And I still get the error. I am running on Windows 7, 64-bit machine.

I run the program as administrator and get the same results.

Can anyone please suggest a solution to this problem?

**Edit1:** *When i went through the 'Scripts' file of Python, i found a file called 'spyder' which is a windows batch file. On opening this file as an administrator, spyder does run normally. But, when i open spider from the start menu, it gives me the above mentioned error. Any idea about why this is happening?*

**Edit2:** *Here's the Path environment variable (since it is too long, i could not add it in the comments):*

C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\PyQt4;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Windows Live;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Windows Live;c:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\iCLS Client\;c:\Program Files\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\OpenCL SDK\2.0\bin\x86;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\OpenCL SDK\2.0\bin\x64;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files\Sony\VAIO Improvement\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Sony\VAIO Startup Setting Tool;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Live\Shared;C:\Users\vaishali\AppData\Local\Smartbar\Application\;C:\Users\vaishali\AppData\Local\Smartbar\Application\;C:\Python27;C:\Python27\DLLs;C:\Python27\Scripts;C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\vtk;C:\Python27\gnuplot\binary;C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\osgeo;C:\Program Files (x86)\pythonxy\SciTE-3.2.2-1;C:\Program Files (x86)\pythonxy\console;C:\MinGW32-xy\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\pythonxy\swig;C:\Program Files (x86)\pythonxy\gettext\bin

Comment: Did you check `Path` environment variable?

Comment: Did you install python 64 bit for sure?

Comment: @SAM, what exactly should i be looking for in the Path environment variable? I know how to access it, but i'm not very sure about what amends need to be made.

Comment: @Madhu, I checked the version of python and it turned out to be 32 bit; following which i searched online for a 64 bit version of python, but there aren't any different versions available for 32 and 64 bit computers.

Comment: What Python did you install exactly? From python.org or some other version?

Comment: I installed 'Python(x,y)-2.7.3.1.exe ' from http://ftp.ntua.gr/pub/devel/pythonxy/

Comment: I've added the Path in the edited version of my question. Since it was too long, i could not incorporate it into the comments.

Comment: I have installed ActivePython-2.7.2.5-win64-x64.msi and it worked fine

Answer (score 0):

Try looking at:

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2669244

Since you mentioned having changed your permissions already, the steps that are particularly relevant are

Method 2: Check to make sure the file location is available

Method 3: Make sure that the file has not been moved or deleted

Method 4: Recreate the shortcut to check for corruption

Method 5: Check  to see if the file has been blocked by Windows

***Method 5*** is what I would recommend doing first as it seems to be one of the more common reasons as to why you can't run executables that you have originally downloaded from the internet.

Comment: Thank you for the prompt reply.

Comment: I've tried all the five methods but the problem still persists.